# null foreignkey mysql can't be null

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have for exemple a parent table and each parent can have one child, so the parent have a children_id

I'd like to set the children_id to 0 if there is no children, but the children with the id 0 don't exist so I have this error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (parent, CONSTRAINT `parent_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`children_id`) REFERENCES `children` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Edit:
A closer example of my case

I have a menu table but a menu can point to an other menu so I have a menu_id in my menu table, the menu_id is linked to the menu id, but the first menu can't have an menu_id

I hope this is a good way to do :)

Thanks

Comment: This seems kind of backward. Usually, you would have a foreign key in the `children` table which is pointing back to the `parent` table, not a FK in `parent` pointing to `children`.

Comment: I add an other exemple

Answer (score 0):

Well, foreign key is a constraint that is enforced by the database so the data remains consistent. There is no workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. Remove the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from the table schema. The foreign key constrain ensures that all elements have a valid parent. But the root element of the hierarchy doesn't have a parent, so you can't require that.
2. Add a child with ID 0, and set `children_id` to this. The rest of your code will have to treat this child specially, as it represents the root of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers but I think I found a solution: create a table to join 2 menus and remove the menu_id from the menu table